# Is it possible to calculate theoretical i/o throughput of CPU?

Tags: networking, cpu, performance, io, chipset

I have machine with i7-2600K and I'm turning it into storage server. It's using P67 chipset which uses 20 Gb/s DMI interface to CPU. There are also pcie x8/x8 slots on board wired directly to CPU. I thought about connecting 8 SATA drives to onboard controllers (using DMI) and 8 SATA drives via DELL Perc 6/i pci-e x8 controller, to export them via quad 10 Gb/s network interface using rr-bonding.

However I'm not sure if this CPU is even capable of pumping 40 Gb/s of i/o in theory, even if we ignore all bottlenecks. Is it possible to estimate maximum theoretical i/o throughput of CPU?

Comment: This CPU has 16 PCIe 2.0 lanes. No network card I found uses more than 8 lanes. Simple math shows it cannot support 40 Gb/s. Why bother looking at anything *but* bottlenecks?

Comment: @DanielB fair point, pci-e 2.0 x8 will support at best 32 Gb/s. Then question still scales to whether there is even theoretical chance to get it. I'm more concerned on whether system can get anywhere close to actual theoretical pci-e bandwidth or is it just number on paper without any relation to reality and real performance is like 16Gb/s at best or something.

Comment: Why not just get (I'm assuming 10Gbps pci-e) the intended card and throughput test it using jperf or similar? My guess is this CPU would be able to handle multiple 10Gbps cards simultaneously. But without all the additional h/w info, no one will be able to give you anything other than a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's using P67 chipset which uses 20 Gb/s DMI interface to CPU. There are also pcie x8/x8 slots on board wired directly to CPU.

Incorrect, peripheral buses (e.g. PCIe and SATA) are not directly connected to the CPU.
Instead of a direct connection to the CPU, PCIe, SATA, USB, and memory have controllers (i.e. auxiliary logic) that interface to some kind of high-speed system bus.  The CPU's address and data buses are typically directly connected to such a system bus.

Note that modern CPU *chips* are highly integrated (e.g. System-on-Chip, SoC, is possible), and the functionality of system chips (e.g. north/south-bridge chips) can be moved closer to the CPU for improved performance by tighter integration.  Such CPU chips may have PCIe and SATA connections because they incorporate those controllers.  But that does not mean that such peripherals are *"wired directly'* to any processor(s).

> Is it possible to estimate maximum theoretical i/o throughput of CPU?

Yes, but throughput using programmed I/O is not a meaningful number.
Since modern computer systems typically perform I/O using 2nd- or 3rd-party DMA (rather than programmed I/O), the CPU is only involved at the start and end of the typical I/O operations.
IOW the CPU would not be the I/O bottleneck.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318145/dma-vs-interrupt-driven-i-o/38165400#38165400
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119491/master-for-interrupt-based-uart-io/38155310#38155310
Therefore your question should be reworded to read:
"*Is it possible to calculate theoretical I/O throughput of a computer?*".

One upper bound for I/O operations would be memory bandwidth.  Since I/O is always between the peripherals and main memory (while ignoring the rare use of peripheral-to-peripheral transfers using a bus master), memory speed can be a bottleneck.
Since main memory is typically much faster than any single peripheral, the issue is more likely to be contention for memory accesses by DMA controllers, bus masters, and the CPU, which needs to be arbitrated by the memory controller.

Comment: But that's not correct. Some PCIe slots *are* connected directly to the CPU.

Comment: I'll admit ignorance of the details of latest Intel processors.  But a direct connection PCIe to the CPU makes no sense.  That's basic, conventional computer architecture.  How does bus mastering work? Please provide some proof.  BTW since some CPU chips also integrate the memory controller, connection to the "CPU chip" doesn't necessarily mean direct connection to the CPU proper.

Comment: @sawdust by _directly_ I meant that there's no interconnect bottleneck between those x8/x8 lanes and CPU. Because chipset usually connects devices that all together require more throughput than interconnect provides. Eg. X399 Threadripper chipset connects usually multiple 5G USB controllers, 8 SATA, pcie x8, pcie x2 and some other junk yet whole chipset is connected by x4 bandwith as shown here: https://images.anandtech.com/doci/11685/kevin_lensing_threadripper_tech_day_legally_approved_7.31.17-page-013.jpg

Comment: @Lapsio -- I can see how that block diagram would lead to incorrect assumptions.  But you need to distinguish between the actual CPU/processor and the "CPU chip".  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_(microarchitecture)) confirms my suspicions:  *"The memory, **PCIe**, SATA, and USB controllers are incorporated into the same chip as the processor cores."* IOW what used to be in the "northbridge" chip are now integrated with the processor(s) in a "CPU chip".  There is no direct connection to the CPU/processor; there are still peripheral/bus controllers involved. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @sawdust you mentioned DMA _controllers_... Is there more than one DMA per system? I thought there's one centralized DMA controller for all devices. Also is DMA an active component, being actual forwarding middleware between device and memory controller pumping all this data back and forth or is it just kind of broker granting devices ability to use memory controller directly? Judging from links you posted I'd say that it's active but I'd be glad if you could confirm I understood correctly.

Comment: Typically a system needs only one DMA controller, which is an actual device, and has a driver in the OS.  In the original IBM PC, the DMAC was a distinct Intel chip.  Use of this system DMAC is called 3rd-party DMA.  DMA using a bus-master (e.g. a PCIe device that's capable) is called 2nd-party DMA.  (Before you ask: memory would be the first-party.)

Comment: The built-in PCIe root port is part of the System Agent, which is undoubtedly part of the CPU, just like the L2 cache is. See [this article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/3922/intels-sandy-bridge-architecture-exposed/4) for details. Of course there is some interconnect involved, but then again: It always is.

Comment: @DanielB -- You're not reading the details correctly, and conflating physical proximity with direct connection.  The generic system bus I refer to is implemented as the "Ring Bus" which interconnects the ***Cores***, Graphics, LLC, and ***System Agent***.  This is still conventional computer architecture.  Note that the article calls the System Agent a *"fancy word for North Bridge"*.  *"the System Agent, which is undoubtedly part of the CPU"* -- No, there's no need to guess, it's clear that the cores are separated from System Agent by a bus.