# Device controller in motherboard

Tags: motherboard

Where are device controllers such as network or USB controller in this diagram? Are they all inside southbridge chipset?
Having ports like USB, keyboard and monitor on motherboard's back panel means that motherboard has USB, keyboard and monitor controllers built-in? Possibly inside super-i/o chipset?
Is a expansion card the same as device controller?
[image: motherboard]

Comment: See the label “Ethernet” in your diagram? No modern chipset will have SCSI support.

Comment: @DoxyLover ok i see, so in general where are device controllers? Does expansion cards include device controller?

Comment: @DoxyLover By having a USB port on back panel of a motherboard, does it mean that motherboard has a USB controller built-in ? And the same for keyboard, mouse and monitor?

Comment: @Offofue For quite long time the motherboards had additional USB chips to supplement 2 or 4 provided by southbridge. New chipsets usually have enough controllers to cover all PC connectors, front and back. From your picture, there is nothing "super" about that box on LPC. It is rather "legacy" support for obsolete technologies

Comment: @Maple Thanks. To be sure, device controllers such as keyboard controller reside in the super-i/o box? And expansion card and device controller are the same ?

Comment: "Are they all inside southbridge chipset?" The diagram clearly shows that.

Comment: FYI your question is very PC motherboard-centric.  Note that there exists System-on-Chip, SoC, which integrates the CPU and numerous device controllers all in one chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: The diagram you are referring to is **old and inaccurate**. On most PC systems made since ~2008, the memory controller and PCIe root controller all exist within the CPU. The component which this diagram refers to as the "northbridge" is no longer part of the chipset. Additionally, there are a number of details in the diagram which are inaccurate even for an older computer. (For example, PS/2 keyboards and mice were never implemented by the Super I/O, and "CMOS memory" is not an off-board component.)

> Having ports like USB, keyboard and monitor on motherboard's back panel means that motherboard has USB, keyboard and monitor controllers built-in?

Mostly correct. However, in many Intel systems, the GPU ("monitor controller") is actually a component of the CPU.

> Possibly inside super-i/o chipset?

No. USB and PS/2 are both typically implemented in the motherboard chipset, not in the Super I/O.

> Is a expansion card the same as device controller?

Sort of? A PCIe or PCI card will typically implement some form of device controller.

Comment: Ah, I found the diagram from Wikipedia, would you please mention some up-to-date and accurate resources to read about the motherboard architecture?

Comment: @Offofue -- Buried in the comments to the answer of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1323301/is-it-possible-to-calculate-theoretical-i-o-throughput-of-cpu) are a few links to block diagrams, as well as a  discussion related to your query.

Comment: @Offofue It can vary significantly from system to system. Your best bet is to look for a block diagram of the specific processor you're interested in. That all being said, [the block diagram sawdust is referring to](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/11685/kevin_lensing_threadripper_tech_day_legally_approved_7.31.17-page-013.jpg) is a decent example of how a modern system may be organized.